# Get Specific version of a deleted file in TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have this really weird problem with TFS that I can't seem to solve.

About a year ago, I created a file called 'extensions.cs' and placed it in source control, let's say around changeset 1000.  At changeset 5000 the file was deleted (as it was no longer needed) and life continued, no problems of course.

Now I need to build an older program from around changeset 3000.  It just so happened to use 'extensions.cs' but I can't check that file out at changeset 3000 (or any changeset for that matter) even though it would have existed at that time.  I can see the file in the source control explorer, but it is grayed out, and its 'latest' status is listed as 'deleted'

It would seem silly that I would not be able to get it back out, so what I am doing wrong, and how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you do a get on the *parent folder* at changeset 3000?  Or 1000, for that matter?

Comment: Yes I can, but anything marked as 'deleted' will not come down the pipe so to speak.

Comment: This functionality should work as you described.  Screen shots maybe?  Of history of that item (to see what changeset it was deleted at)?

Comment: Yeah, I agree that it should, but it doesn't.  This is TFS we are talking about, so it's no surprise.

Comment: And by *it should*, I mean *it works for me*.  I'm wondering about the specific steps you're taking.

Comment: 'Get Specific Version' is the only step I am taking.

Answer (score 25):

Use [`tf undelete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7505w2x.aspx)

Or via the UI:

`Tools` > `Options` > `Source Control` > `Visual Studio Team Founation Server`: Check `Show deleted items in the Source Control Explorer`. Then select one or more files and `Undelete`.

[image: undelete]

Comment: Having to hand pick each affected file seems like a waste of time.  Isn't there some way I can get TFS to behave reasonably.

Comment: Yes, and then I have to switch to the changeset I want, and "resolve conflicts" for each one.  Is this really how TFS wants things to be done?

Comment: If the file was deleted, why would be any conflicts?

Comment: Because 'undelete' counts as a 'modification' according to TFS.  Yes, I agree, it is completely absurd.  I am just going to put this on my list of things that TFS can't do.

Comment: But the deleted file should not exist on your local workspace. If you kept a copy of it, you created a conflict yourself. Avoid that by moving local copies to a non version-controlled folder.

Comment: This is all coming from TFS when I run 'undelete' on the files, and try to 'get specific version'.  Let's face it, the file existed at changeset 3000 and TFS is too stupid to get a copy of it.

Comment: It's very strange that you have this problem, as I use TFS to check out old changesets with deleted files all the time, and it works as I (and you, judging by your comments) would expect, no undelete required. I do always do these checkouts to a directory different than the current one I am working on though.